# In Android ,How to load other shared library in jni_onLoad method?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

In my android project , there are two shared libraries a.so and b.so,now,I want to load b.so in method of jni_onload in a.so, i have written dlopen, dlsym and could find their returns, but it also needs a classLoader, what should i do next,Can you give me some advices? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dlopen` then search for `JNI_OnLoad` in the other library with `dlsym` and run it if this other library registers all natives in `JNI_OnLoad` ([which is recommended](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html)). If you need to use lazy resolving, you need to call `System.loadLibrary()` from `JNI_OnLoad` instead of `dlopen`.